# is there a way to convert an integer to be always a 4 digit hex number using Lua

Tags: lua

I'm creating a Lua script which will calculate a temperature value then format this value as a 4 digit hex number which must always be 4 digits. Having the answer as a string is fine.

Previously in C I have been able to use

```
data_hex=string.format('%h04x', -21)
```

which would return ffeb

however the 'h' string formatter is not available to me in Lua
dropping the 'h' doesn't cater for negative answers i.e

```
data_hex=string.format('%04x', -21)

print(data_hex)
```

which returns ffffffeb

```
data_hex=string.format('%04x', 21)

print(data_hex)
```

which returns 0015

Is there a convenient and portable equivalent to the 'h' string formatter?

Comment: I suggest you try using a bitwise AND to truncate any leading hex digits for the value being printed. So if you have a variable `temp` that you are going to print then you would use something like `data_hex=string.format("%04x",temp & 0xffff)` which would remove the leading hex digits leaving only the least significant 4 hex digits. Or what about using a format of `%4.4x`?

Comment: Thanks Richard, The bitwise AND approach has given the answer I'm looking for

Comment: `data_hex=string.format('%04x', -21):sub(-4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try using a bitwise AND to truncate any leading hex digits for the value being printed.

If you have a variable `temp` that you are going to print then you would use something like `data_hex=string.format("%04x",temp & 0xffff)` which would remove the leading hex digits leaving only the least significant 4 hex digits.

I like this approach as there is less string manipulation and it is congruent with the actual data type of a signed 16 bit number. Whether reducing string manipulation is a concern would depend on the rate at which the temperature is polled.

For further information on the `format` function see [The String Library article](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html).

Comment: This really works for me. Thanks. But i wanna understand how hex to signed decimal conversion would take place ?

Comment: @SagarSahni I don't understand your question about how hex to signed decimal conversion takes place. Hex numbers are unsigned so a conversion from signed decimal to hex is a matter of taking each 4 bit nibble and converting it to a hex digit to generate a sequence of hex digits. Hex to signed decimal conversion requires you consider the most significant bit of the most significant hex digit to be a sign bit indicating whether the value is positive, bit not set, or negative, bit is set. You then do sign extension if needed.